# Problem with double integration

Tags: math-mode, brackets, fractions, integral

I was trying to type a double integral as follows:

```
\documentclass{article}

\begin{document}

\[ 
x=x_0+\int_{t_0}^{t} u_0  +\frac{1}{m} \int_{t_0}^{t} F(t) \,dt \,dt
\]

\end{document}
```

I would like to ask how can I use brackets to separate the inner integral from the rightmost "dt"?
Thank you

Comment: Do you mean this: `x=x_0+\int_{t_0}^{t} \Bigl(u_0 +\frac{1}{m}\int_{t_0}^{t} F(t) \,dt\Bigr) \,dt`?

Comment: Actually I have tried what you have just posted here and it worked perfectly alright, however if I choose brackets [...] instead or parentheses (...) it produces some funny results

Comment: You must have mistyped. `x=x_0+\int_{t_0}^{t} \Bigl[u_0 +\frac{1}{m}\int_{t_0}^{t} F(t) \,dt\Bigr] \,dt` works fine for me.

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps you used an incorrect syntax, as brackets work just fine:

```
\documentclass{article}

\begin{document}

\[ 
x=x_0+\int_{t_0}^{t}\left[ u_0  +\frac{1}{m} \int_{t_0}^{t} F(t) \,dt\right] \,dt
\]

\end{document}
```

[image: result]

If the size of the brackets doesn't suit your needs, replace `\left` and `\right` with other commands like `\bigl` and `\bigr`.

Comment: I have just used the line you posted but the problem persists. I will check whether some other previous commands cause a conflict with the brackets. Many thanks

Comment: @DimosthenisZografos Make sure that you type brackets *without* any backslash before them. `\[` is a command to enter math mode, while `[` is an opening bracket inside math mode.

Comment: I am afraid my Latex is allergic to brackets...

Comment: Can you confirm that compilation fails with just the document above, with no modification? If so, then something is wrong with your installation. If not, then the problem is elsewhere and you should comment out almost everything, and then add lines back one by one until the problem reappears.